# Entity framework entity always connected to context

Tags: entity-framework, objectcontext

if I have this:

```
MyEntities context = new MyEntities ();

Country mycountry = context.Country.Where(c => c.ID == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

why is it that I can access `mycountry.States.FirstOrDefault().Name` if I haven't done any eager or lazy loading on States reference?

does context always stays connected to my entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly, entities are always tracked by a context. This won't be the case on a pure POCO or a self-tracking entity, but those are the exceptions. You can do `Context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries()` to see what is attached.

Comment: tracked is the word I was looking for!, what if I have just the attached entity? (not the context, I have a layered architecture), i just have mycountry how can I dettach it from his context?, so it don't automatically loads his references

Comment: Nevermind, I'm using one object context per request so I got it from there, thank you